# activity retry job after 503 error

Tags: java, activiti

I have many service tasks that call rest services and sometimes the service is not available. I want in my JavaDelegate to be able to infinitely retry the job:

```
@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution)
{
    try
    {
        //call_rest_service
    }
    catch (Exception503 error)
    {
        CommandContext commandContext = Context.getCommandContext();
        JobEntity jobEntity = commandContext.getJobEntityManager().findById(job.getId());
        jobEntity.setRetries(10);
        //then throw original error
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a **SLOPPY** way of doing things, but if you are sure that is what you want to do, I suggest you do something like this :

```
@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution)
{
    int retryMax = 10, retryCount =0;
    while (retryCount++ < retryMax){
      try
      {
        //call_rest_service
      }
      catch (Exception503 error)
      {
        // sleep to not DDoS the server
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }
    }
}
```